# Strains in conformations of cyclohexane

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, isomers, conformers, cyclohexane

I know some the basic kind of strains that can exist in molecules namely Torsional strain (Vanderwaals' strain), steric strain and angle strain.

Is it possible to associate a particular type of strain that causes the majority (and the strain that causes least) of the instability to the molecule eventhough all of the types of strains could possibly exist in that conformation of cyclohexane?

> For example: I was taught that in the twist boat conformation of cyclohexane, the torsional strain is approximately zero but angle strain is huge making this form unstable.

What would be corresponding most and least contributor of strain for chair, half-chair and boat conformations of cyclohexane?

Comment: Why is this question not been answered yet?What extra information should I give? 
Is the question not clear?